# AWS Fast snapshot restore : cost and restore time

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot

I'm confused about fast snapshot restore...

Pricing is at around $0.75 per DSU hour which, assuming you pay for every hour the snapshot exists, is $6000+ a year so I can't have it on all the time.
Or, do you only pay for a DSU only while you are actually doing a restore?

If you do pay DSUs for every hour the snapshot exists, then you have to enable fast snapshot restore just before you begin a restore. 
How long does it take between enabling fast snapshot restore for it to be ready to restore quickly? (I'm assuming the enabling process involves moving all the data from a 'slow server' to  a 'fast server' - lets assume a 1tb volume).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the gist of it.  This service looks pretty pricey if you want to keep it `enabled` all the time.  See the image below for keeping it on for one snapshot in one AZ for one month:

[image]

Per the User Guide:

> It takes 60 minutes per TiB to optimize a snapshot.

If you're cost conscious and don't really need the immediate initialization, I recommend following the EBS Initialization Guide and using `dd` or `fio`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/xvdf of=/dev/null bs=1M
```

With the caveat:

> Incorrect use of dd can easily destroy a volume's data. Be sure to follow precisely the example command below. Only the if=/dev/xvdf parameter will vary depending on the name of the device you are reading.

Or

```
sudo fio --filename=/dev/xvdf --rw=read --bs=128k --iodepth=32 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --name=volume-initialize
```

**References**

[EBS Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/)
[EBS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/faqs/)
[EBS Fast Snapshot Restore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-fast-snapshot-restore.html)
[EBS Initialization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html)